# How to determine http method of any controller path when fetch paths from route.rb in in sitemap.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap-generator-gem

I want to generate a sitemap of a website with more than 300 URL path. Therefore using a sitemap generator, I am fetching URL path from routes.rb file. Now I don't want SEO to crawl through my post url. So, I wanted to determine the Http-method type of controller paths in sitemap.rb. How to do that?

I have tried to fetch http-method with route.path.spec.left.memo.request_method_match, but NoMethodError occue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request method is also called `verb`, so you can do following:

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.collect do |route|
  "#{route.name} = #{route.defaults} = #{route.verb}"
end
```

Different version of rails might have it slightly different, but once you have your route look for `verb`. (check documentation: https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionDispatch/Journey/Route)

I think this gives you enough info to continue.